# A group of students weigh on average 70 Kg, with a standard deviation of 5 Kg...

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, standard-deviation

If a group of 50 students are sampled at random, the probability that their total weight does not exceed 3600 Kg is:

A. 0.9961
B. 0.9977
C. 0.9989
D. 0.9952
E. 0.9931

I know that you must find z-score; (3600-3500)/5

But the official answers say that the standard deviation must be written as so, σS= sqrt(50) × 5 = 35.35

The part where I get confused is when you multiply 5 by sqrt (50) to reflect the new standard deviation, as I think I should instead be writing 5/sqrt 50

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Standard deviation increases in absolute value with more samples; aklthough it will decrease in proportion to a non-zero mean, because it doesn't rise linearly. Multiply. This means the z-score you are interested in is $(3600-3500)/35.35$, so just less than three standard deviations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X_i$ be a random variable with mean $\mu_x$ and variance $\sigma_x^2$ for all $i = 1, 2, ..., n$. Assume $X_i$ are independent and identically distributed.

Let $Z = \sum_i X_i $.

Then, the mean of $Z$, $\mu_z$, is given by

$$ \mu_z = E[Z] $$
$$ = E\left[\sum_i X_i\right] $$
$$ = \sum_i{E\left[X_i\right]} $$
$$ = nE\left[X_i\right] $$
$$ = n\mu_x $$

The variance of $Z$, $\sigma_z^2$, is given by

$$ \sigma_z^2 = V[Z] $$
$$ = V\left[\sum_i X_i\right] $$
$$ = \sum_i{V\left[X_i\right]} $$
$$ = nV\left[X_i\right] $$
$$ = n\sigma^2_x $$

So, the standard deviation of $Z$ is $\sigma_z = \sqrt{n}\sigma_x$.

Now, with $X_i$ normally distributed, we further have that $Z$ is also normally distributed - the [sum of normally distributed random variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables) is itself normally distributed.

In this case, the mean of the sum is

$$ \mu_z = n\mu_x = 50\cdot 70 = 3500 . $$

That's the 3500 you're comparing 3600 against in your $Z$-score.

The standard deviation of the sum is

$$ \sigma_z = \sqrt{n}\sigma_x = \sqrt{50}\cdot 5 . $$

That's what you need to divide by in your $Z$-score.